# Express backend giving empty results on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, fetch

I have an application which retrieves data from the MySQL backend. My other get functions successfully query the MySQL database, but the below function does not, even though the query works when I test it in MySQL workbench.

```
router.get('/duedates', function(req, res, next) {
  con.query("SELECT * FROM due_dates", function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error")
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("Here")
    res.json(JSON.stringify(result))
  });
})
```

I do not understand why, this is basically the same as my other functions, and due_dates is a valid table with data. In the browser, I just get an empty result "[]"

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Here is a working function. For some reason, I cannot send any response from the above function even though the other ones work perfectly fine.

```
router.get('/:day', function(req, res, next) {

  monthToNum = {Aug : '08', Sep: '09'}
  year = req.params.day.toString().split(' ')[3]
  month = monthToNum[req.params.day.toString().split(' ')[1]]
  day = req.params.day.toString().split(' ')[2]

  //let date = req.body.date.toString().substring(0, 10);

  let date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

  con.query("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE date = ?", [date], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var answer = result;
    res.json(JSON.stringify(result))
  });
})
```

Here is how I send the fetch req

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/backend/duedates', {method: "GET", headers: {'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}}).then(res => res.text()).then(resjson => {
      //this.setState({mark: resjson})
      console.log(resjson)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I tried the default fetch request, without the method/get specified, but that didn't work either. Also, I verified that I am fetching the correct location

Comment: Can you please show another _get_ function in order to compare both of them?

Comment: @JoseVasquez added

Comment: How about logging `result` prior to sending it back to see what is retrieved from SQL server?

Comment: @technicallynick Whenever I log, it doesn’t show up, both inside and outside the SQL query. There’s something wrong with the get request but I’m not sure what

Comment: Which package do you use to connect to the mysql database (e.g. `mysql": "^2.18.1`)?

Comment: From that, I'm assuming "Here" is never logged either? Can you add a console statement at the start of this get request (before your SQL query) to confirm your request is being picked up by this function? It's possible that your request is being handled elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, taking another look at this, I think it is not a MySQL issue since the other queries work

Comment: @technicallynick It is not logged at all even if it’s before the query

Comment: Then you have something in your routes that is taking over the request and responding on its behalf. You'll need to show us all of your express routes and the exact request being sent to express.

Comment: @technicallynick edited the post

Comment: /backend/duedates !== /duedates. Try updating your route to include the full uri.

Comment: It uses backend by default